# prometheus doesn't match regex query

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm trying to write a prometheus query in grafana that will select `visits_total{route!~"/api/docs/*"}`

What I'm trying to say is that it should select all the instances where the route doesn't match `/api/docs/*` (regex) but this isn't working. It's actually just selecting all the instances. I tried to force it to select others by doing this:
`visits_total{route=~"/api/order/*"}`  but it doesn't return anything. I found these operators in the querying basics [page](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/) of prometheus. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: May be because you have `/` in the regex. Try with something like `visits_total{route=~".*order.*"}`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

May be because you have `/` in the regex. Try with something like `visits_total{route=~".*order.*"}` and see if the result is generated or not.

Try this also,

```
visits_total{route!~"\/api\/docs\/\*"}
```

If you want to exclude all the things that has the word `docs` you can use below,

```
visits_total{route!~".*docs.*"}
```

Comment: The first option worked but the second one gave an error. I'd rather just exclude docs than manually include everything I want.

Comment: @ninesalt you might need to escape the `*` too. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I didn't need to escape the *. I wanted to exclude two things so I just did it like this `route!~".*docs.*|.*metrics.*"`

Comment: I'd like to add a link to the docs: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/ and I'd like to highlight that sentence: "All regular expressions in Prometheus use RE2 syntax."

Answer (score 6):

The main problem with your original query is that `/api/docs/*` will only match things like `/api/docs` and `/api/docs//////`; i.e. the `*` in your query will match 0 or more `/` characters.

I think what you meant to use was `/api/docs/.*`.

Answer (score 0):

PromQL regular expressions follow [RE2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). As per this using * is tricky, it is considered as x* (where x is last non-empty character preceeding *). Now as per the table x* (* implies x*) and hence the match will be on zero or more occurance of x (in your case /). It is always safe to use ".*" or ".+" unless you intentionally want to match specific character zero or more occurances. More details below[image]